# Why does my program only show one of my Array <String> Food in all of my hashmap data instead of the actual values?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.rhc_checklist;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.rhc_checklist.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by User on 2/28/2017.
 */

public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

private ExpandableListView mListView;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> listHash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
    mListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    initData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listHash) {
    };
    mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

   populateListView();
}

private void initData() {
    String kioskTasks[] = {"Working Properly:", "Guests Waiting:"};
    String foodTasks[] = {"Aromas Lines long:", "Aromas Clean:", "Food Prep Areas Clean:",
            "Kitchen Staff Busy:", "Kitchen Clean:", "EDR Clean and Stocked:", 
 "Staff:Friendly/Helpful/Uniforms:"};
    String tableTasks[] = {"All Tables Being Played:", "Guests Having Fun:", 
  "Staff:Friendly/Helpful/Uniforms:"};
    String hotelTasks[] = {"Less Than 5 Rooms Left at South Tower:", "Less Than 5 Rooms Left at North 
   Tower:",
            "Staff:Friendly/Helpful/Uniforms", "Front Desk Agent Present:"};
    String casinoTasks[] = {"Slot Attendants Helping Guests:", "Beverage Servers Asking For Drinks:",
            "Soda Machine Stocked and Maintained:", "Casino Host Visible and Talking to Guests:", 
  "Slots Being Played/Fun:",
            "Ash Trays Being Emptied:", "Glasses Being Picked Up:", "Cage Lines:", "Security Available:",
            "Floor Feels Busy:", "Restrooms Clean and Stocked:", "Staff:Friendly/Helpful/Uniforms:",
            "Trash on Floor:", "Attendants Walking in Pairs:", "Masks Worn by Staff:", "Masks Worn by Guests:"};
    String cleanTeamTasks[] = {"Staff on Task:", "Following Proper Procedure: 1. Spray Cloth 2. Wipe Buttons 3. Wipe Screen 4. Wipe Chair:"};
    String travelersTasks[] = {"Truck Lot Full:", "Showers Utilized:", "Clean:", "RV Park Full:",
            "Staff:Friendly/Helpful/Uniforms:"};
    String parkTasks[] = {"Clean:", "Security Observed:", "Well Lit:"};
    String cstoreTasks[] = {"Staff:Friendly/Helpful/Uniforms:", "Clean/Organized:", "Pumps Working:",
            "Bathrooms Clean:", "Well Lit:"};
    String securityTasks[] = {"Anything Going On?:", "Ride Along with Lot Patrol:", "Staff Walking in Pairs:"};
    String equestrianTasks[] = {"Event:", "Attendance:", "Guests Enjoying Show:", "Impact on Casino Floor:"};
    String constructionTasks[] = {"Secure Access Points:", "Equipment/Tools Exposed/Unattended:",
            "Equipment Subject to Theft or Misuse:", "Fire Hazards/Trash/Chemicals:", "Trip Hazards",
            "Sharp or Low Hanging Objects:", "Adequate Signage:", "Adequate Lighting:"};
    String early = "Early Shift: ";
    String late = "Late Shift: ";
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listHash = new LinkedHashMap<>(500);
    listDataHeader.clear();
    listDataHeader.add("Kiosks");
    listDataHeader.add("Food and Beverage");
    listDataHeader.add("Table Games");
    listDataHeader.add("Hotels");
    listDataHeader.add("Casino Floor");
    listDataHeader.add("Clean Team");
    listDataHeader.add("Travelers Center");
    listDataHeader.add("Parking Lot");
    listDataHeader.add("C-Store");
    listDataHeader.add("Security");
    listDataHeader.add("Equestrian Center");
    listDataHeader.add("Construction Areas");

    List<String> Kiosks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < kioskTasks.length; i++){
        Kiosks.add(kioskTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Food = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < foodTasks.length; i++){
        Food.add(foodTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Table = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableTasks.length; i++){
        Table.add(tableTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Hotel= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < hotelTasks.length; i++){
        Hotel.add(hotelTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Casino= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < casinoTasks.length; i++){
        Casino.add(casinoTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Clean = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cleanTeamTasks.length; i++){
        Clean.add(cleanTeamTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Travelers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <travelersTasks.length; i++){
        Travelers.add(travelersTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Park= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parkTasks.length; i++){
        Park.add(parkTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> CStore = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cstoreTasks.length; i++){
        CStore.add(cstoreTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Security= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < securityTasks.length; i++){
        Security.add(securityTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Equestrian= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < equestrianTasks.length; i++){
        Equestrian.add(equestrianTasks[i]);
    }
    List<String> Construction = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < constructionTasks.length; i++){
        Construction.add(constructionTasks[i]);
    }

    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Kiosks);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Food);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Table);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Hotel);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Casino);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(5), Clean);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(6), Travelers);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(7), Park);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(8), CStore);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(9), Security);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(10), Equestrian);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(11), Construction);
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Not allowed to embed images yet so https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5wig.png

This is a screenshot of the output on the android emulator. You can see that only the foodTasks are being shown on all categories. I can't seem to figure out why...

From what I can tell the Lists are all populated properly I added code to make sure at one point and they all have the appropriate data in them. They just aren't being added into the HashMap for some reason. In Fact for the Construction and Casino categories the app crashes and says they are null.

Edit: ExpandableListAdapter Class for more error checking.

```
package com.example.rhc_checklist;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return listDataHeader.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(i);
    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final String childText = (String)getChild(1,i1);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Use listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after putting values in listHash. That way your adapter is notified of the change in values

Comment: Can you post your expandable list adapter code too , there might me some problem?

Comment: Sure just a second. I will try Sarah's suggestion and post the expandable list adapter code.. ok where should I put the listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() because at the end of my init function crashes it says null.

Comment: Nothing changes when adding listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You know what... I don't think its adapting to a bigger size after hitting the foodTasks... it crashes saying index 7 size7

Comment: So in my HashMap I can see that all of the values are actually set correctly to the HashMap, so the issue isn't with the HashMap assignment at all, but with the actual population of the ListView

Comment: Error in ExpandableListAdapter.java at line 80 typo. I accidentally put final String childText = (String)getChild(1,i1); instead of final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);

Answer (score 0):

I had a typographical error in file `ExpandableListAdapter.java` at line 80.
I accidentally put

```java
final String childText = (String)getChild(1,i1);
```

instead of

```java
final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
```

Thanks for all of your help guys. This is solved.

Comment: Thank you Abra, sorry about not putting the code blocks that time. Alsofor the grammatical corrections it was a bit stressful yesterday, so I had just typed real quick and didn't do anything special